# Scala Writeable of AnyContentAsMultipartFormData - play 2.6

Tags: scala, playframework, writable

I have those lines in my code

```
  implicit val anyContentAsMultipartFormWritable: Writeable[AnyContentAsMultipartFormData] = {
    MultipartFormDataWritable.singleton.map(_.mdf)
  }
```

I had to upgrade my play version from play 2.5 to play 2.6.6, and now those lines are not working. This is the problem:

```
value mdf is not a member of play.api.mvc.AnyContentAsMultipartFormData
```

I see that mdf is a member of that class at documentation, and it not seems that this changed in play 2.6.6.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: How are you compiling? Any chance your IDE is not up to date?

Comment: Version 2021.2.3 IntelliJ. What else should I check? Any dependency?

Comment: In doubt, compile with SBT directly?

Comment: it supposed to be mfd instead of mdf.